# Way to detect when a child is removed from a DisplayObjectContainer?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there a way to detect when a child is removed from a DisplayObjectContainer? I tried overriding removeChild(), but this doesn't appear to trigger when the child is removed by adding it to another container (via a call to addChild() on the new container). I'm not aware of any events that trigger, either...

I know that you can do this with higher-level Flex classes, but I'm using a Pure AS3 project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**
As Roy has pointed out in the comments, because events (including Event.REMOVED) [bubble up](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/eventbubbles-eventcancelable-and-eventcurrenttarget), then simply adding an event listener for the REMOVED event to the `DisplayObjectContainer` is sufficient; it will be called when any child objects are removed from the container (even when it's because the object was added to a different container).

The event's `target` property will be the child that is being removed, and the `currentTarget` will always be the container itself.

Note that this event will also fire if the entire container itself is removed from *its* container; a simple `if (e.target == e.currentTarget) return;` should handle that case.

Original answer below:

---

You can add an event listener for the [`Event.REMOVED` event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#event%3aremoved) to every `DisplayObject` that is added to your `DisplayObjectContainer`. Then the object itself will tell you that it's been removed, instead of having to rely on the `DisplayObjectContainer` for notifications.

If this also doesn't fire when the object is moved from one container to another, then as a workaround you could also listen for the ADDED event and check if the display object is still in your container when that fires.

Don't forget to remove the event listeners once the object is removed from your container, otherwise you could end up with memory leaks, multiple calls to event listeners for the same object, etc.

Comment: Thanks a mil - I checked and Event.REMOVED is indeed fired when moving between containers.

Comment: You do not have to add Event.REMOVED to EVERY displayobject. You need to add it ONLY to the DisplayObjectContainer. When a child is removed, the event will reach the container, and the child removed will be the event.target property.

Comment: @Roy: That event is directly inherited from DisplayObject. Won't it only fire when the entire container is added or removed, not the objects within it?

Comment: Nope, because events dispatched by DisplayObjects bubble to their parents (event bubbling). Thanks to the bubbling, you can catch all the children events with one listener at the parent, which is a lot neater and easier to clean up.

Comment: @Roy: You're totally right. I wasn't thinking of bubbling, and in any case didn't expect event.REMOVED to be bubbled up by default (but it is!). If you add that as an answer I'll upvote :-)

Comment: Your answer is already accepted, it's best if you add it to yours. I appreciate the offer, though :)

Answer (score -1):

As long as the child is on the stage, you can listen to `Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE`. This example traces "remove".

```
private function init():void {
    var parent:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var test:Sprite = new Sprite();
    test.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, remove);
    parent.addChild(test);
    stage.addChild(parent);
    parent.removeChild(test);
}

private function remove(e:Event):void {
    trace("remove");
}
```